# Why did Leia give her emphatic "diplomatic mission" excuse when confronted by Vadar?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

(Rogue One spoilers)

> **Leia:** Darth Vader. Only you could be so bold. The Imperial Senate will not sit still for this. When they hear you've attacked a diplomatic...
>
> **Vadar:** Don't act so surprised, Your Highness. You weren't on any mercy mission this time. Several transmissions were beamed to this ship by rebel spies. I want to know what happened to the plans they sent you.
>
> **Leia:**  don't know what you're talking about. I am a member of the Imperial Senate on a diplomatic mission to Alderaan...
>
> **Vadar:** You are part of the Rebel Alliance and a traitor! Take her away!

Huh?

Mere minutes/hours earlier she had been part of a criminal fleet that brutally attacked a Imperial base.

Her men had clamored aboard her starship with a hard copy of Death Start plans spitting distance from Vadar who pursued them, and watched as Leia's ship pull away.

It's hardly a mission of diplomacy, a fact I very much doubt that the Senate would dispute.

---

Why did Leia insist on such a obvious lie? Who was she trying to convince? Vadar? Her men? The stormtroopers? Herself?